# Get bookmark index using system.Information()

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm using below line to get a selected drop down from an endoresment.

```
ActiveDocument.FormFields(ActiveDocument.Range.Bookmarks(Selection.Information(30)).Name).Dropdown.Value
```

But I'm unable to get the correct bookmark index through `Selection.Information(30)` hence getting incorrect bookmark name.

Can any one please help me here.

Comment: Selection.information (30)  gives the current bookmark index with that index I can get the bookmark name but unfortunatly i am not getting the current book mark index. Is there any way to get current bookmark index?

Comment: I was on a mobile device that last few days so couldn't research this in detail. I hope the information in the Answer helps...

Comment: Hi cindy,,,It works but, I am using like Activedocument.formfields(selection.bookmarks(1).name).enable = False  but after that statement we are unprotecting the activedocument then the disabled bookmark again becoming enable after unprotecting. Can you help me here

Comment: What works? The code I proposed in the Answer? If yes, please mark that as the "Answer" since the original question has been taken care of. Start a *new question* for a new topic, with full information on how to reproduce the behavior, including the type of protection involved. Stack Overflow is not a "forum" where an endless discussion is possible - it's a Question & Answer format.

Answer (score 0):

The more "conventional" way to get the name of the currently active/selected bookmark name is:

```
Selection.Bookmarks(1).Name
```

Since this appears to be a form field, it's also possible to get the name via that collection:

```
Selection.Range.FormFields(1).Name
```

In a comment the request is for the bookmark index, although the request in the Question is for the bookmark name... In any case, to get the bookmark index get the count of all bookmarks from the start of the document to the end of the selection. (Note that this gets the index of the last previous bookmark, which is not necessary *in* the selection):

```
bkmIndex = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Range.End).Bookmarks.Count
Debug.Print ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(bkmIndex).Name
```

Please note that `Information(30)` is an old Word Basic value (I had to look it up in 1995 literature) that has no official equivalent in the VBA object model. It still works for reasons of backwards compatibility, but in such cases there are no guarantees that it will continue to work.